# Trying to understand node.js package bundling inefficiency in the web

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I live in a web world which is probably very outdated now in terms of whats available. The projects i work with are asp.net core with individual js and css files - bundled up in to files which are common throughout the pages (page navigation code/layouts for example) and separated for individual page requirements. But where 3rd party libraries are loaded separately (jquery for example).

I'm brand new to node.js, and although i likely don't fully grasp the concept, i'm really failing to understand the benefits of one - bundling all dependencies in to a single file.

My scenario:

I have multiple typescript files, most common, but at least 1 unique file used for a page specific purpose. Almost every page uses the JQuery library.

So in my page specific (and common files) i import jquery

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

The output of my typescript file is using the "CommonJS" module. So it outputs it as

```
var $ = require("jquery");
```

But because the browser doesn't understand "require" - i use a bundler to convert this .js file in to a file which contains the full jquery library within it (i'm currently playing with browserify and webpack).

All this so far i understand the need for. But what i'm failing to grasp is if i have 100 pages, all with a different function (and so all have their own typescript file and entry point) - meaning they all individually need to be bundled up with the JQuery library.

How is this in any way more efficient than just calling a single jquery library file for all the pages, which is cached and reused? Putting the whole JQuery library in to every single bundle.js file thats loaded surely can't be better?

My main goal is to use typescript files and a package manager like npm to allow me to easily manage and update my javascript packages (rather than the old way of copying the dist in to a folder and them slowly getting out of date). And although being able to "import" any package easily in to typescript is beneficial, it seems like a step back in progress that all my libraries are being downloaded 100's of times.

Am i misusing node.js? Or are there alternative ways to using typescript with external libraries without having to bundle everything up?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Normally the entire app is bundled at once so only a single copy of jquery is bundled. Both webpack and browserify work this way by default so you must be doing something custom if you're getting multiple copies of jquery in your bundle

Comment: Also, you're almost not using node.js at all. You are just using tools written in node.js. Just like when I'm typing this in Google Chrome I'm not using C++. You're only really using node.js if you are writing a server with it instead of PHP or Ruby or Java or Python etc. If you're really using node.js you won't be using jquery and discussions about bundlers are not necessary

Comment: I get both those points. In regards to the first, how does having a single bundle work on large scale applications? If i have a 100 pages (tiny example of many real world websites) all with specific code - bundling all that in to a single file surely can't be any more efficient? And in regards to your second point of hardly using node.js - i agree, but what alternatives are there when wanting to use typescript and 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Single bundle does not mean a single file. Webpack can split the bundles into chunks that are demand loaded and big projects that use webpack such as React.js use this feature

Comment: As for your second question. Typescript is using node.js. You are using typescript to write browser (not node.js) code. As such I personally would not consider that you are using node.js. You can use Google Chrome or Firefox without using C++ even though both use C++